# Using a keyhole contour for this specific problem

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

> I want to compute 
>   $$\int\limits_0^1 {1 \over \sqrt[3]{x^2 -x^3}} dx$$

My book suggests to use a keyhole contour with small circles at branch points $0$ and $1$.

The answer is ${2 \pi \over \sqrt{3}}$.

I have tried many things but I do not get an answer, but instead the addition of several integrals, some which go to zero as $\epsilon \to 0$ and $R \to \infty$.

Comment: It gets even more confusing if you don't write out what you've done.  Saying you tried things and that you got some integrals isn't really enlightening to us readers.  Mind taking the time to **show** what you tried?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference   kindly pick up mathjax.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh This user seems to already know MathJax (hopefully) if you check his/her profile.

Comment: @SiongTheyGoh:  Nope... The OP apparently doesn't know MathJax.  I did all the typesetting.

Comment: @David be careful not to change the question itself though.

Comment: @Simply:  A typo... quickly caught.  But yes.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I just check the past posts, the first posts seems to be without mathjax. =(

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh D: That's quite horrible!  For some basic information about writing math at this site, please see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773), and don't forget that you can check the [edit]'s done to your questions!.

Comment: Find some branch of $f(z) = z^{-2/3}(1-z)^{-1/3}$ that is analytic for $|z-1/2| > 1/2$. By the Cauchy integral theorem you'll get that $ \int_{|z|= R}f(z)dz$ (easy to compute when $R \to \infty$) is also $C\int_0^1 x^{-2/3}(1-x)^{-1/3}dx$ where $C = 1-e^{-2i \pi /3}$

Answer (score 2):

**METHODODLGY $1$:  Real Analysis**

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2-x^3}}\,dx&=\int_0^1 x^{-2/3}(1-x)^{-1/3}\,dx\\\\
&=B(1/3,2/3)\tag 1\\\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(1/3)\Gamma(2/3)}{\Gamma(1/3+2/3)}\tag 2\\\\
&=\Gamma(1/3)\Gamma(1-1/3)\tag 3\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi/3)}\tag 4\\\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt 3}
\end{align}$$

**NOTES:**

In arriving at $(1)$, we use an integral representation of the Beta function, $B(a,b)=\int_0^1 x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}\,dx$ for $a>0$, $b>0$.

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we use the relationship between the Beta and Gamma functions, $B(a,b)=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$

In arriving at $(3)$, we used the fact that $\Gamma(1)=1$.

And in going from $(3)$ to $(4)$, we use the Euler's reflection formula, $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$ for non-integer values of $z$.

---

**METHODODLGY $2$:  Complex Analysis**

First, we choose to cut the plane with branch cuts from $0$ to $-\infty$ and from $1$ to $-\infty$.  With the plane cut accordingly, the arguments of $z$ and $1-z$ are given by

$$-\pi<\arg(z)\le \pi$$

and

$$-2\pi <\arg(1-z)\le 0$$

Moreover, the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{z^2-z^3}}$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,1]$.

Integration over the "dog bone contour" $C$, not the "keyhole" contour, can be written

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{C_\epsilon} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{z^2-z^3}}\,dz&=\int_{\epsilon}^{1-\epsilon} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2-x^3}}\,dx+\int_{1-\epsilon}^\epsilon \frac{1}{e^{-i2\pi/3}\sqrt[3]{x^2-x^3}}\,dx\\\\
&+\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{i\epsilon e^{i\phi}}{\sqrt[3]{(1+\epsilon e^{i\phi})^2\,(-\epsilon e^{i\phi})}}\,d\phi\\\\
&+\int_{2\pi}^0 \frac{i\epsilon e^{i\phi}}{\sqrt[3]{(\epsilon e^{i\phi})^2}(1-\epsilon e^{i\phi})}\,d\phi\tag 5
\end{align}$$

As $\epsilon \to 0^+$, the third and fourth integrals on the right-hand side of $(5)$ approach $0$, which reveals that

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\oint_{C_\epsilon} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{z^2-z^3}}\,dz=(1-e^{i2\pi/3})\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2-x^3}}\,dx$$

We can evaluate the contour integral by using Cauchy's Integral Theorem to deform the contour to a circle, centered at $0$, with radius $R$, traversed clockwise.  This yields

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\oint_{C_\epsilon}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{z^2-z^3}}\,dz&=-\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{iRe^{i\phi}}{\sqrt[3]{(Re^{i\phi})^2-(Re^{i\phi})^3}}\,d\phi\\\\
&=-i2\pi \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{e^{-i\pi}}}\\\\
&=-i2\pi e^{i\pi/3}\tag 6
\end{align}$$

Setting $(5)$ and $(6)$ equal,solving for the integral of interest, and simplifying, we obtain

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^3}}\,dx=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt 3}$$

as expected!

Comment: Beautiful !! Could you please explain to this poor soul two things :A little explanation as to why the args are given as to what is written , and how to apply the principal of deformation of path in the last computation ...(I am learning complex Analysis on my own ,and I do not have access to a good teacher)

Comment: The arguments for $z$ and $1-z$ were chosen.  But they are not unique.  For example, we could have chosen $0<\arg(1-z)\le 2\pi$, as Felix Marin chose.  As for contour deformation, Cauchy's Integral Theorem states that if $f$ is analytic on $D$, then $\oint_C f(z)\,dz=0$ for any rectifiable curve in $D$.  [This video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xp1Q9SHe6NU) explains the idea.

Comment: It is not immediately obvious that $\sqrt[\large3]{z^2-z^3}$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,1]$. I have added an addendum to my answer showing this.

Comment: @robjohn Well, is it arduous to see that $\frac{2(2\pi)+2\pi}{3}=2\pi$?  Hence, with the plane cut as chosen, $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{z^2(1-z)}}$ is indeed continuous for $z\in (-\infty,1)$.

Comment: @MarkViola: I am not sure how "$\frac{2(2\pi)+2\pi}{3}=2\pi$" makes it obvious that $\frac1{\sqrt[3]{z^2-z^3}}$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus{[0,1]}$. However, $\frac1{\sqrt[3]{z^2(1-z)}}$ is *not* continuous on $(-\infty,1)$; it is discontinuous at $z=0$. Even if it were, continuity on a line does not guarantee analyticity on $\mathbb{C}\setminus{[0,1]}$. Furthermore, why do we choose the branch cuts mentioned in the first paragraph if the function is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,1]$?

Comment: @robjohn  There was a typo in my comment.  Of course $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{z^2(1-z)}}$ is discontinuous on $[0,1]$.  I had intended to write that it is continuous on $(-\infty,0)$, not $(-\infty,1)$.  Since the complex logarithm is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0)$ (this can be shown easily from the Cauchy-Riemann equations), then the composite function $z^c=e^{c\log(z)}$ is likewise.  Then, $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{z^2(1-z)}}$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,1)$ by virtue of the two branch cuts from $(-\infty,0)$ and $(-\infty,1)$.

Comment: @robjohn ... And in fact, $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{z^2(1-z)}}$ is continuous on $(-\infty,0)$.  To see this, we examine the its behavior across the overlapping branch cuts from $(-\infty,0)$.  On the "upper" side, its argument is $-\frac{2(\pi)-0}{3}=-2\pi/3$ while on the "lower" side its argument is $-\frac{2(-\pi)+(-2\pi)}{3}=4\pi/3$.  Inasmuch as $-2\pi/3$ is the same argument (modulo $2\pi$) as $4\pi/3$, continuity is preserved.

Comment: @MarkViola: I am not arguing the point that $\frac1{\sqrt[3]{z^2-z^3}}$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,1]$. I actually verified that in an addendum to my answer. What I am saying is that it is not obvious by just looking at $\frac1{\sqrt[3]{z^2-z^3}}$.

Comment: @robjohn Yes, I understand what you are saying.  I was trying to respond, point-by-point, to your previous note.  The very last part of that response was my attempt to explain how one can quickly see that it is analytic where the branch cuts overlap.

Comment: @Mark Viola,Why was exp{(-i(pi)} used to obtain (6)? If we use exp{(i(pi)} , we do not get the required answer , as I have computed ...Both though represent the number minus 1 ....

Comment: @herashefat That is an excellent question.  Look at the way we defined $\arg(z)$ and $\arg(1-z)$.

Comment: @Mark Viola Thanks for your detailed response to this question ,,,You mention that arg(z) and arg(1-z) are not unique , but changing would change the answer (is this true??) I cannot see how they were chosen is your choice ...Also should not the branch cuts be from zero to negative infinite infinity and then from 1 to POSITIVE infinity??

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use $x=\sin^2t$ and $u=\sqrt[3]{\cot{t}}$.

Finally calculate $6\int\limits_0^{+\infty}\frac{u^3}{u^6+1}du$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt[\large3]{x^2 -x^3}}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1x^{-2/3}(1-x)^{-1/3}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^{-2/3}\left(\frac1{x+1}\right)^{-1/3}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(x+1)^2}\tag{2}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{-2/3}}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}\\
&=\frac1{1-e^{-4\pi i/3}}\int_\gamma\frac{z^{-2/3}}{1+z}\,\mathrm{d}z\tag{4}\\
&=\frac{2\pi ie^{-2\pi i/3}}{1-e^{-4\pi i/3}}\tag{5}\\[4pt]
&=\frac\pi{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)}\tag{6}\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3}\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: rewrite the integrand
$(2)$: substitute $x\mapsto\frac{x}{x+1}$
$(3)$: algebra
$(4)$: $\gamma$ is the keyhole contour $$\left[i\epsilon,Re^{i\arcsin\left(\frac\epsilon R\right)}\right]\cup Re^{i\left[\arcsin\left(\frac\epsilon R\right),2\pi-\arcsin\left(\frac\epsilon R\right)\right]}\cup\left[Re^{-i\arcsin\left(\frac\epsilon R\right)},-i\epsilon\right]\cup\epsilon e^{i\left[\frac{3\pi}2,\frac\pi2\right]}$$
$(5)$: the residue of $\frac{z^{-2/3}}{1+z}$ at $z=-1$ is $e^{-2\pi i/3}$
$(6)$: Use [Euler's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)
$(7)$: evaluate

Diagram of $\gamma$ ($R\to\infty$ and $\epsilon\to0$):

[image]

---

**Addendum to Mark Viola's Answer**

In Mark Viola's answer, it is stated that

> Moreover, the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{z^2-z^3}}$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,1]$.

We can write
$$
\begin{align}
\log\left(\sqrt[\large3]{z^2-z^3}\right)
&=\frac13\log\left(z^2-z^3\right)\\
&=\frac{\log(2)}3+\frac13\int_{-1}^z\frac{2w-3w^2}{w^2-w^3}\mathrm{d}w\\
&=\frac{\log(2)}3+\int_{-1}^z\frac13\left(\frac2w+\frac1{w-1}\right)\mathrm{d}w\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
The sum of the residues at $0$ and $1$ of the integrand in $(8)$ is $1$. This means that if we circle both singularities, we get a total integral of $2\pi i$. Therefore, via exponentiation, $\sqrt[\large3]{z^2-z^3}$ is defined unambiguously by the integral in $(8)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over \root[{\large 3}]{x^2 -x^3}} =
> \int_{0}^{1}x^{-2/3}\,\pars{1 - x}^{-1/3}\,\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$.

I'll consider the following definitions of $\ds{z^{-2/3}}$ and $\ds{\pars{1 - z}^{-1/3}}$:
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\ds{z^{-2/3} =
\verts{z}^{-2/3}\exp\pars{-\,{2 \over 3}\,\mrm{arg{\pars{z}}}\,\ic}\,,\quad
-\pi < \mrm{arg}\pars{z} < \pi\,,\quad z \not= 0.}
\\[3mm]
\ds{\pars{1 - z}^{-1/3} =
\verts{1 - z}^{-1/3}\exp\pars{-\,{1 \over 3}\,\mrm{arg{\pars{1 - z}}}\,\ic}
\,,\quad
0 < \mrm{arg}\pars{1 - z} < 2\pi\,,\quad z \not= 1.}
\end{array}\right.\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Note that $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{with}\ x\ <\ 0~}}$:
\begin{align}
&\left.\pars{x + \ic 0^{+}}^{-2/3}\pars{1 - x - \ic 0^{+}}^{-2/3}
\,\right\vert_{\ x\ <\ 0}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{\pars{-x}^{-2/3}\exp\pars{-\,{2 \over 3}\,\pi\ic}}
\bracks{\pars{1 - x}^{-1/3}\exp\pars{-\,{1 \over 3}\,2\pi\ic}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-x}^{-2/3}\pars{1 - x}^{-1/3}\exp\pars{-\,{4\pi \over 3}\,\ic}
\label{2.a}\tag{2.a}
\\[1cm]
&\left.\pars{x - \ic 0^{+}}^{-2/3}\pars{1 - x + \ic 0^{+}}^{-2/3}
\,\right\vert_{\ x\ <\ 0}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{\pars{-x}^{-2/3}\exp\pars{-\,{2 \over 3}\bracks{-\pi\ic}}}
\bracks{\pars{1 - x}^{-1/3}\exp\pars{-\,{1 \over 3}\,0\,\ic}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-x}^{-2/3}\pars{1 - x}^{-1/3}\exp\pars{{2\pi \over 3}\,\ic}
\label{2.b}\tag{2.b}
\\[1cm]
&\mbox{such that}\quad \eqref{2.a}\ \mbox{and}\ \eqref{2.b}\ \mbox{are}\ equal.\
\mbox{A similar situation occurs when}\
\left.\pars{x \pm \ic 0^{+}}\right\vert_{\ x\ >\ 1}
\end{align}
It shows that, with definitions \eqref{1}, $\ds{z^{-2/3}\pars{1 - z}^{-1/3}}$
has a *branch-cut* along $\ds{\bracks{0,1}}$.

---

The integration 'slightly' above and below the branch cut yields
\begin{align}
&\int_{1}^{0}
x^{-2/3}\pars{1 - x}^{-1/3}\exp\pars{-\,{1 \over 3}\,2\pi\ic}\,\dd x +
\int_{0}^{1}x^{-2/3}\pars{1 - x}^{-1/3}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{1 - \exp\pars{-\,{2\pi \over 3}\,\ic}}\int_{1}^{0}
x^{-2/3}\pars{1 - x}^{-1/3}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\exp\pars{-\,{\pi \over 3}\,\ic}
\bracks{\exp\pars{{\pi \over 3}\,\ic} - \exp\pars{-\,{\pi \over 3}\,\ic}}
\int_{0}^{1}x^{-2/3}\pars{1 - x}^{-1/3}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\ic\exp\pars{-\,{\pi \over 3}\,\ic}\root{3}
\int_{0}^{1}x^{-2/3}\pars{1 - x}^{-1/3}\,\dd x\label{3}\tag{3}
\end{align}
The contribution from the residue 'at infinity' yields
\begin{align}
&2\pi\ic\,
\lim_{z \to 0}\bracks{z\,{1 \over z^{2}}\,z^{2/3}\pars{1 - {1 \over z}}^{-1/3}}
=
2\pi\ic\,\lim_{z \to 0}\pars{\verts{z - 1}^{-1/3}\expo{-\pi\ic/3}} =
2\pi\ic\expo{-\pi\ic/3}\label{4}\tag{4}
\end{align}

---

$$
\eqref{3} = \eqref{4} \implies
\bbx{\int_{0}^{1}x^{-2/3}\pars{1 - x}^{-1/3}\,\dd x = {2\root{3} \over 3}\,\pi}
$$