integrating $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^{2}-x^{3}}}dx$

The question is to evaluate:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^{2}-x^{3}}}\text{d}x $$
using elementary methods, without using complex analysis.

I have a fundamental understanding of integral calculus, including techniques such as substitution, integration by parts, and the evaluation of basic definite and indefinite integrals. The integral above is solved on various sites using advanced tools like complex analysis, which are currently beyond my scope.

My Work:
$$
\text{I} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^{2}-x^{3}}}\text{d}x = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x \cdot \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{x} - 1}}\text{d}x
$$
$\text{Let}\;\;\dfrac{1}{x} - 1 = t^3 \implies x = \dfrac{1}{1+t^3} \implies \text{d}x = -\dfrac{3t^2}{(1+t^3)^2} \text{d}t
$
Substitute these into the integral:
$$
\text{I} = \int_{\infty}^{0} \frac{1+t^3}{t} \cdot \frac{-3t^2}{(1+t^3)^2}\text{d}t
 = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{3t}{1+t^3}\text{d}t
$$
This is where my progress ends. I can not further think of any substitution which would do some further progress in evaluating this integral. Any help is appreciated.

Hint: since $1+t^3=(1+t)((1+t)^2-3t)$, the integrand is$$\frac{1+t}{1-t+t^2}-\frac{1}{1+t}.$$

OHHHHH, I'm so dumb, did not expect it to be so easy..

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397003/integrate-int-01-frac1-sqrt3x2-x3dx?noredirect=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2367600/using-a-keyhole-contour-for-this-specific-problem?noredirect=1.

$$\int \frac{3t}{1+t^3}dt=\frac{1}{2}\ln(t^2-t+1)-\ln(t+1)+\sqrt{3}\arctan\left({\frac{2t-1}{\sqrt{3}}}\right)$$

That is definitely within my scope. I can’t believe I overlooked something as straightforward as partial fraction decomposition.

Hint
$$\frac{3t}{t^3+1}=\frac{3t}{(t+1)(t^2-t+1)}=\frac{t+1}{t^2-t+1}-\frac{1}{t+1}$$
$$\frac{t+1}{t^2-t+1}=\frac 12  \frac{2t-1}{t^2-t+1}+ \frac 32\,\frac{1}{t^2-t+1}$$
For the last one, complete the square.

Here's the simple non-elementary solution,
$$ I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^{2}-x^{3}}}dx $$
$$ I=\int_{0}^{1} x^{-\frac{2}{3}}(1-x)^{-\frac{1}{3}}\,dx $$
From this,
$${\displaystyle \mathrm {B} (z_{1},z_{2})=\int _{0}^{1}t^{z_{1}-1}(1-t)^{z_{2}-1}\,dt}$$
$$I=B\left(\frac13,\frac23\right)=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3}$$

As neat as it is, I'm not sure using the beta function qualifies as elementary method though :-)

I'm sorry I don't know about the beta function.

How do you prove the Gamma function's reflection formula without complex analysis? (If your answer relies on the sine function's Weierstrass product, how do you prove that without complex analysis?)

Hiding Gamma function to undergraduates creates a serious handicap.

Noting that
$$
I=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{3 t}{1+t^3} d t \stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}}{=}  \int_0^{\infty} \frac{3}{t^3+1} d t
$$
Averaging the two versions of the integral $I$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{3}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t+1}{t^3+1} d t \\
& =\frac{3}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^2-t+1} d t \\
& =6 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 t-1)^2+3} d t\\&=\frac{6}{2 \sqrt{3}}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 t-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right]_0^{\infty} \\
& = \frac {2 \pi}{\sqrt 3}
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps.

This should be the accepted answer!

Thank you for your appreciation and support.
